# elixir UTC date time casting in ecto models and params

Tags: datetime, casting, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

When I create a table I define my table field like this

```
add(:arrive_at, :utc_datetime)
```

and in the the model which is used for **changeset**

```
attr(:arrive_at, :utc_datetime)
```

But when I send the datetime even with timezone from any device, the changeset will ignore the timezone info and only cast the datetime part e.g **2018-02-25 18:40:52.492657+03:00** will cast to **#DateTime<2018-02-25 18:40:52.492657Z>**. How do I get the correct cast working

Comment: That's strange.. what do you get if you run this in `iex -S mix`: `Ecto.Type.cast :utc_datetime, "2018-02-25 18:40:52.492657+03:00"`. I get `{:ok, #DateTime<2018-02-25 15:40:52Z>}`.

Comment: @Dogbert I got **{:ok, #DateTime<2018-02-25 18:40:52.492657Z>}**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FXi_vXehH1TzzUCyTb2z7lRyqE84eiYI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: **Erlang/OTP 20** and elixir version **1.6.1 (compiled with OTP 20)**

Comment: I think I find the strange behavior reason, its old ecto version **"ecto": {:hex, :ecto, "2.1.6"**(copied from mix.lock file). I didn't upgrade ecto because it uses long integer as primary key if I upgrade ecto, I have to change many triggers, functions etc. But if there is a way that I can upgrade ecto and use same integer key then its all good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in old ecto version or this was not handled in ecto **2.1.6** dont know exactly. But I got it fixed by upgrading ecto to latest version and passing **config :app, App.Repo, migration_primary_key: [type: :serial],** to my database config options. (Because upgrading without setting primary key types updates all of the integer serial keys to big integer and I had to update a lot of functions and triggers this way)